# Pyinstaller generated executable is huge in size

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a python application and I want to generate a standalone executable application.
I am using pyinstaller to generate the executable. The problem here is that the generated application is huge in size. I have added my .spec file. could someone help me how to reduce the executable size. Also the application has dependency on some images and json files. i have to manually move them to the excutable path. how to make this automatic?

the .spec file is :

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['ADP_Multi_Tool.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\sj3kc0\\wkspaces\\ADVRADAR_HIL_Replay_Tool'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,  
          [],
          name='ADP_Multi_Tool',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
```

Comment: how huge is huge?  Remember the executable needs to include the python runtime, after all

Comment: it is around 22MB

Comment: That’s not huge. Don’t forget it includes the python interpreter and all the needed packges. Write a ‘hello world’ simplest possible and turn it into an exe, check the size, then add some of your imports and build the exe, see the size grow. One thing you should do is build in a venv which only has the packages installed that you need. Otherwise you risk something like `tqdm` which imports a shed-load of packages it works with like tkinter and scikit pulling all those packages in if they’re in the Python env. I had that and I got a 500MiB exe!